# Facebook API displaying French authorize page on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm not sure how this happened, but all of a sudden the Facebook "authorize this app" dialogue view is now in French. Any idea how this may have occurred?

[image: Facebook authorize dialogue view]

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a Facebook bug...

this morning it was setted to indonesian, calling it from italy and germany...

we saw a lot of Facebook developers discussing about it in their forums... so nothing much we can do from our apps...